# $ \frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{b+c} + \frac{1}{a+c}=2 $ then $ \sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab} \geq \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that if  $$ \frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{b+c} +  \frac{1}{a+c}=2 $$  then  $$\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{ab} \geq \frac{3}{2}$$

I tried to use AM-GM inequality and Titu's lemma and was able to show that $a+b+c\geq3$ and $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab}\geq3abc$.

Can someone give a hint on how to continue?

**Edit**: I apologize for all the typos in the original submission.(I'm new to the website and i don't know if i should delete the original post)
This is my work on the probleme:
By Titu's lemma we have:

$$ \frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{b+c} +  \frac{1}{a+c} \geq \frac{9}{2a+2b+2c}$$
Then by using the condition we end up with
$$ a+b+c \geq \frac{9}{4} $$
by AM-GM we have:
$$ \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{a+b} \leq \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{ab}}
$$
so $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}} \geq 4 $$
in the other hand by AM-GM we have
$$ 3\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}} \leq  (\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}})^{2}$$
using those later results i ended up with $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab}\geq \sqrt{12abc}$$

Comment: Consider $a=b=c=\frac34$, then $a+b+c=\frac94<3$.  Can you show your working for those results you got?

Comment: Smells like Jensen inequality to me.

Comment: What $\sum \frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{b+c} +  \frac{1}{a+c}$ means? Did you meant $\frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{b+c} +  \frac{1}{a+c}$?

Comment: The inequality is incorrect, check $a= b=5/4, c = 0$. Then $\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{a+b} = 2$ but $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{ab} = 5/4 < 3/2.$